# Intriguing Inequality Question? Find the minimum value of $\sum (a1-a2)^2$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4 $ be $4$ real numbers such that $\sum a_i =0 $ and $\sum a_i^2=1$. Then , the minimum value of $(a_1-a_2)^2+(a_2-a_3)^2+(a_3-a_4)^2+(a_4-a_1)^2$ lies in the range :-

**A)**$ (0,1.5)$
**B)**$(1.5,2.5)$ **C)**$(2.5-3.5)$ **D)** $(3.5-4.5)$

This question was asked in the Mathematics section of the 2017 edition of the KVPY , one of the most prestigious national level examinations conducted in India .

The answer is **(B)**

---

Obviously , being an objective exam , the layman’s approach to tackling a question like this would be to assume values (say $-0.5 , -0.5 ,0.5 $ and $0.5$) , but is there a formal way of solving this problem using a standard inequality ? I have tried rearrangement on $\sum a_i^2$ , but this simply gives me a minimum of $0$ , with no case of equality.

Comment: Hold on- if $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = 0.5$, then the minimum value of your expression is 0.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2596571/42969.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: Your values do not satisfy $\sum a_i =0 $ .

Comment: lol good point well made